# Combine one action and one filter

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, actions

I want to show an error message in Woocommerce checkout page, and remove the order button.
I can use one action and one filter:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_checkout_error', 9 );
function add_checkout_error() {
    wc_print_notice( __( 'An error message.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}

add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'remove_order_button_html' );
function remove_order_button_html( $button ) {
    $button = '';
    return $button;
}
```

How can I combine them? If I put the filter inside the action function, it doesn't work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_checkout_error', 9 );
function add_checkout_error() {

    $error=1;
    if ($error==1){
    wc_print_notice( __( 'An error message.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'remove_order_button_html' );
    }
}

function remove_order_button_html( $button ) {
    $button = '';
    return $button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the filter function must be inside the action function, because if it isnt it is not recognize. So I think. At least with variables is like this.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_checkout_error', 9 );
function add_checkout_error() {
    wc_print_notice( __( 'An error message.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'remove_order_button_html' );
    function remove_order_button_html( $button ) {
            $button = '';
            return $button;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but that's not the point. Doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't define functions inside other functions, it's bad practice and could break in future versions of PHP. There is no reason not to move the function back into the top level